# Optimization for non linear function

Tags: optimization

I have an injective function $f:N\mapsto \mathbb{R}^k$ with $N\subset \mathbb{R}^{k-d}$ open. Let $v_n\in \mathbb{R}^k$ is a sequence of random variable. I'd like to find $\hat x\in N$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\|f(\hat x)-v_n\|
\end{equation*}
as small as possible when $\|.\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm.

I know that if $f$ is linear then , i.e., $f(x)=Ax$ then the least square
$\hat x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tv_n$ is the solution of my problem. Is it correct?

My question is: if $f$ is not necessary linear, how will I solve my problem? Any suggestion? Thank you in advance

Comment: Does $F$ have a specified form? For example, known to be quadratic, or is it simply general?

Comment: No @StellaBiderman, $F$ has no special form. It can be general function

Comment: Thanks @ChristianBlatter for your correction. I've edited it

Answer (score 0):

The point $\hat x$ where
$$x\longmapsto \|f(x)-v\|$$
reaches the minimum (if $\exists$) is the same that the point where
$$x\longmapsto \|f(x)-v\|^2=\langle f(x)-v,f(x)-v\rangle$$
reaches the minimum. The difference is that the second function is differentiable and the minimun will be a critical point.

Comment: Thank @Martin-Blas. But, I forgot to write $v$ is random. Sorry for my forget.